# Unable to handle width of next tr if rowspan comes in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have problem with table conversion from XML to HTML using XSLT. I converted rowspan and colspan in separate row(entry), but if both rowspan and colspan come in single row(entry, colspan and rowspan) is not converting. I have tried so many ways but I didn't get the exact output.

I have a table and colgroup, I am taking table td width form colgroup which are mentioned on top in table.

I need to define width of the td which is specific colgroup. For Ex: for 2nd td in table, width is taken from 2nd colgroup.

It is working fine. but when colspan occur in td it takes only position col width value. I want that when colspan occur it should take all previous col sum in td width.

I am unable to handle rowspan.

Input:

```
<document>
    <table size="s" orient="portrait" tablebodyrowalign="top" shading="true" width="100%"
        type="ignore" align="center" border="1">
        <colgroup>
            <col width="26%"/>
            <col width="5%"/>
            <col width="36%"/>
            <col width="12%"/>
            <col width="21%"/>
        </colgroup>
        <thead/>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td bottom="single" align="center" valign="bottom">
                    <para margintop="0pt" marginbottom="0pt" style="TableBodyNoIndent">
                        <emph fontcolor="000000" fontsize="20">
                            <emph type="Bold">Signature</emph>
                        </emph>
                    </para>
                </td>
                <td align="left" valign="top">
                    <para style="TableBodyNoIndent"/>
                </td>
                <td bottom="single" align="center" valign="bottom">
                    <para margintop="0pt" marginbottom="0pt" style="TableBodyNoIndent">
                        <emph fontcolor="000000" fontsize="20">
                            <emph type="Bold">Title</emph>
                        </emph>
                    </para>
                </td>
                <td align="left" valign="top">
                    <para style="TableBodyNoIndent"/>
                </td>
                <td bottom="single" align="center" valign="bottom">
                    <para margintop="0pt" marginbottom="0pt" style="TableBodyNoIndent">
                        <emph fontcolor="000000" fontsize="20">
                            <emph type="Bold">Date</emph>
                        </emph>
                    </para>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="bottom" fill="FFFFFF">
                    <para/>
                </td>
                <td align="left" valign="top" fill="FFFFFF">
                    <para/>
                </td>
                <td align="left" valign="middle" fill="FFFFFF">
                    <para/>
                </td>
                <td align="left" valign="top" fill="FFFFFF">
                    <para/>
                </td>
                <td align="left" valign="top" fill="FFFFFF">
                    <para/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bottom="single" align="center" valign="bottom" fill="FFFFFF">
                    <para margintop="0pt" marginbottom="0pt" style="TableBodyNoIndent">
                        <emph fontcolor="000000" fontsize="20">/s/ Bryant R. Riley</emph>
                    </para>
                </td>
                <td align="left" valign="top" fill="FFFFFF">
                    <para style="TableBodyNoIndent"/>
                </td>
                <td rowspan="2" align="center" valign="middle" fill="FFFFFF">
                    <para margintop="0pt" marginbottom="0pt" style="TableBodyNoIndent">
                        <emph fontcolor="000000" fontsize="20">Co-Chief Executive Officer and
                            Director</emph>
                    </para>
                    <para margintop="0pt" marginbottom="0pt" style="TableBodyNoIndent">
                        <emph fontcolor="000000" fontsize="20">( </emph>
                        <emph fontcolor="000000" fontsize="20">
                            <emph type="Italic">Principal Executive Officer</emph>
                        </emph>
                        <emph fontcolor="000000" fontsize="20">)</emph>
                    </para>
                </td>
                <td align="left" valign="top" fill="FFFFFF">
                    <para style="TableBodyNoIndent"/>
                </td>
                <td align="left" valign="top" fill="FFFFFF">
                    <para margintop="0pt" marginbottom="0pt" style="TableBodyNoIndent">
                        <emph fontcolor="000000" fontsize="20">August 3, 2018</emph>
                    </para>
                </td>
            </tr>


            </tbody>
    </table>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="td">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="style">
      <xsl:if test="@fill">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('background-color: ','#',@fill, ';')"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="@align">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('text-align:',@align,';')"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:variable name="colpos" select="sum(preceding-sibling::td/@colspan) + count(preceding-sibling::td[not(@colspan)]) + 1" />
      <xsl:variable name="colspan" select="if (@colspan) then number(@colspan) else 1" />
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('width:', sum(ancestor::table/colgroup/col[position() ge $colpos and position() lt $colpos + $colspan]/number(replace(@width, '%', ''))), '%;')"/>  
    </xsl:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="rowspan" select="@rowspan"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please edit your question adding the desired outcome XML/HTML.

Comment: @zx484 my problem is that when rowspan occur the following-siblig::tr/td same position()  td width should be ignore and next td width apply on it.

Comment: I only found a solution for `rowspan="2"`, but not greater values. So no general solution. It's really tricky.